# Using a String Variable in a Double Loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I need to loop through some data that has two variables: season and school. If I hold the school variable fixed (below) I can get it to loop through the season I specify:

```
library(XML)

# parameters
first_season <- 2014
last_season <- 2015

# seasons 
num_seasons <- as.numeric(last_season - first_season + 1)
seasons <- seq(first_season, last_season, by=1)

# defense
defense <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:num_seasons) {
  url <- paste("http://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/schools/wisconsin/", seasons[i], ".html", sep = "") 
  df <- readHTMLTable(url,which=4, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=F)
  df$season = seasons[i]
  defense <- rbind(defense, df)
  rm(df)
  print(seasons[i])
}
```

My issue is I don't know how to add a) an additional parameter to loop on and b) how to handle the parameter if it's non-numeric.

My list of schools is in a table/column `colleges$school`^

```
> head(colleges$school)
[1] "Air Force"           "Akron"              
[3] "Alabama"             "Alabama-Birmingham" 
[5] "Alameda Coast Guard" "Alcorn State"
```

^ the url will always be `lower(colleges$school)` with `-` replacing  but I can control for that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand (b). Do you mean passing in the parameter (e.g. school[j]), or storing the data (e.g. seasons[i]).

All I did was add an outer loop and iterate over colleges. I store the results in a new df called school_defense.   I don't have your school list so I cannot test it.

```
 library(XML)

# parameters
first_season <- 2014
last_season <- 2015

# seasons 
num_seasons <- as.numeric(last_season - first_season + 1)
seasons <- seq(first_season, last_season, by=1)

# schools 
schools <- unique(lower(colleges$school))

# defense
school_defense <- data.frame()
for(j in 1:length(schools)){
    defense <- data.frame()
    for (i in 1:num_seasons) {
      url <- paste("http://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/schools/", school[j],"/", seasons[i], ".html", sep = "") 
      df <- readHTMLTable(url,which=4, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=F)
      df$season = seasons[i]
      defense <- rbind(defense, df)
      rm(df)
      print(seasons[i])
    }
 defense <- data.frame(school = rep(school[j], nrow(defense)), defense)
 school_defense <- data.frame(school_defense, defense)
}
```

Comment: I replaced the single `#schools` line with `# schools 
colleges <- as.data.frame(c("Arizona State", "Michigan", "Wisconsin"))
names(colleges) <- "school"

schools <- unique(tolower(colleges$school))
schools <- gsub(" ", "-", schools)` and I get the error `Error in paste("http://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/schools/", school[j],  : 
  object 'school' not found`

Comment: @FrankB. simple typo: you named the variable `schools` so just add s `schools[j]`

Comment: Ya, I noticed that afterwards. I changed every instance of `schools` to `school` under the `# schools` line and get the error: `Error in data.frame(school_defense, defense) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 73`

Comment: change it to  school_defense <- rbind(school_defense, defense)